# Send SMS from phone with bluetooth and C#

Tags: c#, bluetooth, sms

I want to connect from the PC via bluetooth to a mobile phone an then make the phone to send a SMS. Is this possible? 
Any suggestion are apreciated. 
Thank you!

Comment: Does the phone when connected via bluetooth present itself as a modem?  if so any sms library with AT/pdu/modem support will work; http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm#gsmcomm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if it can be done or not the way you described, but if your goal is just to get the PC to send SMS, and you don't care how its done, check out [Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/) - awesome platform and *incredibly* easy to use (and very inexpensive to boot).